# How can i replace text with a text box using event using component interaction in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

i have created the a button and i want on click to disply the text box which replaces the existing text that i get from api

trnmnt-name.copmonent.ts

```
export class TrnmntNameComponent implements OnInit {

      @Output() public trnameEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
      constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){
    }
    trEvent(){
        this.trnameEvent.emit("Put text box here"); 
      }
    }
```

trnmnt-name .component.html

```
<div class="TrnmtName">
      Hello There 
      <button type="submit" (click)="trEvent()" >Edit</button>  
</div>
```

tournament.component.ts

```
export class TournamentComponent implements OnInit {


  public message:"";
   constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  recieveMsg($event)
  {
    this.message = $event

  }
}
```

tournament.component.html

```
<div>
{{message}}
        <app-trnmnt-name (trnameEvent)="recieveMsg($event)"[trname]="tournamentdata?.tournament?.name"></app-trnmnt-name>
</div>
```

any solution to solve this

Comment: You are missing the @Input operator

Comment: What currently happens?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this. the `(click)` event in span will turn `editingOn = true` and that will replace *text* with *input box*. clicking on save button will call the `save()` and will turn the `editingOn=false`.

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="!editingOn; else notEditing">
         <p><span (click)="editingOn=!editingOn">{{yourTextModel}}</span></p>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #notEditing>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourTextModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <button type="button" (click)="save();editingOn=!editingOn">Save</button>
    </ng-template>
```